# Is it possible to load jpg into QPixmap (or any other Qt image format), without it being converted to bitmap internally?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a large number of nicely compressed jpg images and when they are loaded from either QImage::loadFromData or QPixmap::loadFromData, the heap allocation jumps up massively (5mb allocated for 200kb JPEG). Is there any way to prevent this, short of doing my own paint / using some other lib?

Comment: It's not possible at all since somehow the pixels must be shown on the screen so they must be available somewhere in memory

Comment: They are available ...in the .jpg, do you think jpeg cannot be decompressed during the paint?

Comment: Are the names/paths of the jpegs all known at build time?  If so you could bind them all as resources to the executable and create the pixmaps (or images)  as `QPixmap(":/path/to/file.jpg")` as needed.

Comment: @G.M. Nope they are not, + I have them only in form of QByteArray, maybe i could write them to files and tie QIcons to them, i dont know if it would help but it sounds convoluted and inefficient

Comment: For the record, when I open a full screenshot of my desktop saved as jpg or saved as bmp, I see in my task manager that the memory used by MSPaint jumps by the same amount in both cases, and drops back to the same level when I close the images, in both cases. **IMHO**, this hints at @chehrlic's comment being correct (this is a normal behavior, be it in Qt or elsewhere), which incidentally could have been coming from me too.